# Openlayers 3 containsExtent

Tags: javascript, openlayers, extents

According to the API:

```
ol.extent.containsExtent(extent1, extent2)
```

checks to see whether extent1 is contained by extent2.

With the following variables:

```
extent1 = [-93, 44, -94, 45];

extent2 = [-95, 43, -92, 46];
```

`ol.extent.containsExtent(extent1, extent2)` returns `false`, though `extent1` is clearly within `extent2`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr;**
You just need to switch the order of your parameters.

---

There are two issues here:

1. Your extents are invalid
2. The API documentation is wrong

(*In retrospect the order of your extents does not affect the outcome, but it is important to have standards..*)

Further to point 1 above, `extent1` contains the lower right, and upper left coordinates respectively.  Whereas `extent2` contains the lower left and upper right coordinates.

The proper format for extents is `[minx, miny, maxx, maxy]`. ([API](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.html#Extent))

```
var extent1 = [-94, 44, -93, 45];
var extent2 = [-95, 43, -92, 46]; 
ol.extent.containsExtent(extent1, extent2); // returns false still?
```

Looking at the `ol.extent.containsExtent` function on [GitHub](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/v3.5.0/src/ol/extent.js#L175), we see the implementation as:

```
 return extent1[0] <= extent2[0] && extent2[2] <= extent1[2] &&
   extent1[1] <= extent2[1] && extent2[3] <= extent1[3];
```

Initially, we can see that the first condition is not satisfied for your example:

```
/* -94    <=   -95   (false) */
extent[0] <= extent2[0]
```

This function will simply not work for coordinates in the negative hemisphere.  But, looking further into the code we see that the latest version has updated the API documentation: ([via](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/commit/b606f4996b7ce651c2446af8d1278a4f1fd8de67)).  So clearly, the documentation is wrong - not the code.

```
/**
 * Check if one extent contains another.
 *
 * An extent is deemed contained if it lies completely within the other extent,
 * including if they share one or more edges.
 *
 * @param {ol.Extent} extent1 Extent 1.
 * @param {ol.Extent} extent2 Extent 2.
 * @return {boolean} The second extent is contained by or on the edge of the
 *     first.
 * @api stable
 */
```

So, if you execute `ol.extent.containsExtent(extent2, extent1)` it will give you a valid response.

Comment: API docs were fixed very recently: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/3693 will be in upcoming 3.6 release.

Comment: Like I said in my post...